Android Emulator Problem: Only displays a black android screen for a split second and the emulator disappears
I've had this error for quite some time now and I don't know how to fix this. I tried most of the methods online and unfortunately, they're outdated and doesn't work anymore.
So, I have an Android Studio (Ladybug), and I went for the Android Device Manager. I tried to run one of the emulators that I already installed. Given that I already did some of the methods that I tried online (i.e., wiping data, deleting the multiinstance.lock file) but it still won't work. I only see the emulator for a split second and then it won't show anymore before and after booting. see picture here
This is also true when I'm doing dart and flutter. I tried to use an emulator, but it only shows me an error. So, I have no choice but to run it on a live server which also sucks and frustrating to use. I truly appreciate if someone can help me fix this issue. Thanks!
Edit: My currently installed emulators are (which by the way installed from scratch, because I also reinstalled Android Studio thinking it would help to resolve the issue):
Pixel API29 (Android 10.0) ("Q") | x86
Pixel API35 (Android 15.0) ("VanillaIceCream") | x86_64

Please [edit] your question and specify if this also happens with an emulator that you created from scratch. Please also specify if the chosen API level matters.

Have you tried running the emulator from the command line to gather more info.    Add -verbose.  Use -list-avds to find your avd name proper.  Also try creating a new emulator with Ladybug; I've had issues where emulators created from previous releases do not work with latest/later releases.
